# Migrating from IntentService to JobIntentService for Android O

Tags: android, background-service, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

Previously I was using IntentService to send data to the server periodically. However, since Android O limiting background task and processes I am moving towards JobIntentService.

My Activity code to schedule an alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, EventBroadcastReceiver.class);

// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, EventBroadcastReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Setup periodic alarm every half hour
long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
```

And my Service is as follows

```
public class EventAnalyticsService extends JobIntentService {    
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        // Perform your task
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Receiver for this code is

```
public class EventBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, EventAnalyticsService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

However this is not working for Android O when app is in background and if I use `context.startForegroundService(myIntent);` to start my service it is throwing exception as `Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()`

Comment: stop using alarmmanager to schedule arbitrary tasks that are not alarms. Use jobscheduler

Comment: Is there any workaround for lower SDK version?

Answer (score 5):

`JobIntentService` is there mostly for a service that will be invoked from the UI, such as a service to perform a large download, initiated by the user clicking a "Download!" button.

For periodic background work, use `JobScheduler` and a `JobService`. If you need to support older than Android 5.0, use a suitable wrapper library (e.g., Evernote's `android-job`), one that will use `JobScheduler` on newer devices and `AlarmManager` on older devices.

Alternatively, stick with `AlarmManager`, but use a foreground service.